# Word/Phrase to describe someone who wants ALL or NOTHING of it?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

For example, if you are aiming for 100% and you get -- say -- 98% in one exam, you won't really care because you were aiming for 100% and that 2% is enough for you to disregard everything and any ambition of aiming the highest even though it probably won't make a difference in the long run.

i.e. You want something to be completely perfect ELSE you don't care for it at all.

Comment: You'd just be [an "**all-or-nothing**" guy](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22an+all+or+nothing+guy%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) in common parlance.

Answer (score 6):

I think you are describing a  ***[perfectionist](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/perfectionist)***:

> - somenone with the  propensity for being displeased with anything that is not perfect or does not meet extremely high standards.

(AHD)

Comment: The "ELSE ..." in the question make me think to "*intransigent*" or "*inflexible*" that  characterize the refusal to compromise or to abandon an extreme position or attitude. As these words don't really fit with the idea of perfection, they may qualify "perfectionist", i.e. "intransigent or inflexible perfectionist".

Comment: @Graffito - intransigent or inflexible carry 'negative'  connotations, and  would not add  any significant  improvement to the definition of "perfectionist" that, to me , well exemplifies an attitude to 'extremely high standard' of execution.

Comment: In his question, *silenceislife* wrote "2% is enough for you to disregard everything ..." and "...ELSE you don't care for it at all." A perfectionist will be displeased with imperfections, but he won't necessarily have a "all-or-nothing" attitude.

Comment: Well, that depends on the "perfectionist" involved. That is anyway the closest I can think of. If you have a more appropriate suggestion that may fit the context, please post an answer.

Comment: I voted for "*perfectionist*": its the *perfect* word for "aiming at 100% ... be completely perfect". *Intransigent* or *inflexible* were only suggestions to bear the idea that any imperfection "is enough for you to disregard everything". I agree that these adjectives are not a major improvement and may be disputable.

Answer (score 3):

Consider [**Completionist**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/completionist)

> *n.* (in a video game) a player who attempts to complete every challenge and earn every achievement or trophy
>
> *I’m not really a completionist, so I skipped the side missions and focused on the main story quests.*

Or try [**Completist**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/completist)

> *n.* a person who attempts to complete a collection or set, especially a collector who wants to collect an example of every item in a particular field
>
> *This recording is a must for obsessive Sinatra completists.*
>
> *I'd only recommend this movie to Hepburn completists.*

Answer (score 2):

Consider, ***hardnose***

> hard-nosed *adj.*
>
> :  being tough, stubborn, or uncomprising [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hard%E2%80%93nosed)
>
> hardnose *noun*
>
> A hard-nosed person [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hardnose)
>
> *Quiz: Are you a hard-nosed negotiator or a soft touch?* [British Council](https://www.teachingenglish.org.uk/sites/teacheng/files/Negotiations%205_Clinching%20the%20deal_worksheet.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Although it is rarely used the word you are looking for is Absolutist.
noun
1.
the principle or the exercise of complete and unrestricted power in government.
2.
any theory holding that values, principles, etc., are absolute and not relative, dependent, or changeable.

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation of why _absolutist_ is a good fit for the situation that the poster describes. A relevant definition of the word from a good dictionary would do a lot to strengthen your answer. Thanks.